# Water is dripping out of a cone of semi vertical angle $\pi/4$ at $2cm^3/s$. Find the rate of decrease of slant height at height= $\root\of2$

Tags: calculus

> Water is dripping out of a conical funnel of semi vertical angle $\pi/4$ at a rate of $2cm^3/s$. Find the rate at which the slant height is decreasing when the height is $\sqrt2$ cm.

*My approach:*
$V=1/3\ \pi r^2 h$
$r=h$
$V=\pi h^3/3$
$dV/dt=\frac{\pi}{3}3h^2\ dh/dt$
Solving further and putting value of height we get $dh/dt=1/\pi$
Now, $l=\root\of2 h$, so $dl/dt= \root\of2/\pi$

I can't figure out what's wrong with my solution. The answer given in my book is $1/\root\of2 \pi$.

Comment: Your solution seems correct to me. Maybe another case of a typo in a book.

Comment: @ShraddheyaShendre okay, thank you!